# Several "with .... as var1" with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this:

```
  if condition1:
    with func1() as var1:
      with func2() as var2:
        # a lot of stuff here

  else:
    with func2() as var2:
      # the exact same stuff as above
```

Is there any way to do something like?

```
  if condition1:
    with func1() as var1:
       ????

   # func2() is called anyway
   with func2() as var2:
     # a lot of stuff here
```

as opposed to this:

```
  def some_stuff():
    # a lof of stuff

  if condition1:
    with func1() as var1:
      with func2() as var2:
        some_stuff()

  else:
    with func2() as var2:
      some_stuff()
```

As you can see, `func2()` is called anyway, by `func1()` only when the condtion is true.

Comment: Can you explain the statement "I want something like a preprocessor"?

Comment: @BhargavRao, updated.

Comment: Wouldn't putting `with func2() as var2:` outside the `if else` block work as intended?

Comment: Please don't use offensive language. We expect everyone to be nice here

Comment: what would you put inside "func1() as ..." then?

Comment: `some_stuff()`. Put `with func2() as var2:` and then have the if-else block. Inside the `if` block put `with func1() as var1` and then continue as you intend to.

Comment: why not use `with func1() as var1, func2() as var2: `

Comment: What do you need `var1` for when the exact code can run without that variable in the other case?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution remains separating out "lots of stuff" into a separate function. However, you could handle something like this using [`contextlib.ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) (requires v3.3+).

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    if condition:
        var1 = stack.enter_context(func1())
    var2 = stack.enter_context(func2())

    ... # stuff

# all context managers handled by stack are exited at the end of the block
```

Answer (score 2):

you could create a conditional context manger with dummy context manager when condition False.

and you can merge both your var1 and var2 context manager with a comma

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def dummy_context_manager():
    yield None

with func1() if condition1 else dummy_context_manager() as var1, func2() as var2:
    # do your stuff here
    some_stuff()
```